# App crashes on firebase database getinstance

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Before this error appeared, I updated firebase-auth to version 16.0.2 in attempt to solved a "Program type already present: com.google.android.gms.internal" error. Would that be related?

Crash log:

```
> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method zzboy()Z in class
> Lcom/google/firebase/FirebaseApp; or its super classes (declaration of
> 'com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp' appears in
> /data/app/com.bignerdranch.android.instagramclone-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk)
>                       at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(Unknown Source)
>                       at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(Unknown Source)
>                       at com.bignerdranch.android.instagramclone.Utils.FirebaseMethods.<init>(FirebaseMethods.java:57)
>                       at com.bignerdranch.android.instagramclone.Share.NextActivity.onCreate(NextActivity.java:49)
>                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6372)
>                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1110)
>                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2432)
>                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2539)
>                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:168)
>                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1378)
>                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
>                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5659)
>                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:822)
>                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:712)
```

project gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files

        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        google() // Google's Maven repository
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

app gradle:

> ```
> apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
>
> android {
>     compileSdkVersion 26
>     buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
>     defaultConfig {
>         applicationId "com.bignerdranch.android.instagramclone"
>         minSdkVersion 19
>         targetSdkVersion 26
>         versionCode 1
>         versionName "1.0"
>         testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
>     }
>     buildTypes {
>         release {
>             minifyEnabled false
>             proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
>         }
>     }
> }
>
> dependencies {
>     implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
>     androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2',
> ```
>
> {exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
>           })
>           implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
>           implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
>           testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
>
> ```
>     implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
>
>     //Design library for Coordinator Layout and Toolbars
>     implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
>
>     //BottomNavigationViewEx Library
>     implementation 'com.github.ittianyu:BottomNavigationViewEx:1.2.4'
>
>     //Circle ImageView
>     implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
>
>     //Universal Image Loader
>     implementation 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
>
>     //firebase authentication
>     implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.2'
>
>     //firebase database
>     implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.6.0'
>
>     //firebase storage
>     implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1'
>
> }
>
> //Firebase
> apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your dependency for firebase-database is really old.  Try using the latest version:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
```

The latest versions of each dependency are all [listed on this page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#available_libraries).

Answer (score 1):

I upgraded to 4.2.0 and it worked

`classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'`